# Angular client with signalR service not fire controller method

Tags: signalr, angular-services

I have angular service where i got methods which are called from server when user connect or disconnect from my app

```
(function () {
//'use strict';
app.service('PrivateChatService', ['$rootScope', '$location', function PrivateChatService($rootScope, $location){
    var online_users = [];
    var proxy = $.connection.chatHub;

    return {
        addOnlineUser:
            proxy.client.newOnlineUser = function (user) {
                    var newUser = ({
                        connectionId: user.ConnectionId,
                        UserName: user.UserName
                    });
                    online_users.push(newUser);
                    $.connection.hub.start()
            },

            removeOfflineUser: proxy.client.onUserDisconnected = function (id, user) {
                var index = 0;
                //find out index of user
                angular.forEach(online_users, function (value, key) {
                    if (value.connectionId == id) {
                        index = key;
                    }
                })
                online_users.splice(index, 1);
                $.connection.hub.start()
            },

        }
}])})();
```

Here i got controller method which i want to be fired when server calls newOnlineUser

```
    PrivateChatService.newOnlineUser(function (user) {
        $scope.online_users.push(newUser);
        console.log("newOnlineUser finished");
    });
```

So my question is. Is it possible to make with generated proxy or i have to use non-generated proxy access to those methods with which i am not very familiar.

With generated proxy as i show above it never reach my controller method to update my data in controller scope

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody responded, what i find somehow odd. I found out this is working. I am not sure if this is good aproach since nobody answered and i didnt find any information how should this be solved.

```
app.service('PrivateChatService', ['$rootScope', '$location', function PrivateChatService($rootScope, $location){
    var online_users = [];        
    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

    function signalrCall(eventName, callback) {
        proxy.on(eventName, function (user) {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(proxy, args)
            })
        });
        connection.start();
    }
    return {
        addOnlineUser: function (eventName, callback) {
            signalrCall(eventName, callback);               
        },

        getActiveUsers: function (eventName, callback) {
            signalrCall(eventName, callback);
        },

        removeOfflineUser: function (eventName, callback) {
            signalrCall(eventName, callback);
        }
    }
}])
```

angular controller methods

```
    PrivateChatService.addOnlineUser("newOnlineUser", function (user) {
        var newUser = ({
            connectionId: user.ConnectionId,
            UserName: user.UserName
        });

        $scope.online_users.push(newUser);
        console.log("newOnlineUser finished");
    });

    PrivateChatService.getActiveUsers("getOnlineUsers", function (onlineUsers) {     
        angular.forEach($scope.online_users, function (scopeValue, scopeKey) {
            //loop through received list of online users from server
            angular.forEach(onlineUsers, function (serverListValue, serverListKey) {
                if (!(serverListValue.ConnectionId == scopeValue.connectionId)) {
                    var newUser = ({
                        connectionId: serverListValue.ConnectionId,
                        UserName: serverListValue.UserName
                    });
                    $scope.online_users.push(newUser);
                }
            })
        })
        console.log("getOnlineUsers finished");
    });

    PrivateChatService.removeOfflineUser("onUserDisconnected", function (user) {
            var index = 0;
            //find out index of user
            angular.forEach($scope.online_users, function (value, key) {
                if (value.connectionId == user) {
                    index = key;
                }
            })
            $scope.online_users.splice(index, 1);
    });
```